# Ошибка в buildozer

Tags: java, python, linux, jdk11, buildozer

Использую ОС linux manjaro

Версия jdk - java-11-openjdk

```
~/mykivy >>> buildozer android debug                                      
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Read available permissions from api-versions.xml
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Система управления пакетами Debian «dpkg», версия 1.20.5 (amd64).
Это свободное программное обеспечение. См. условия распространения в
Универсальной общественной лицензии GNU версии 2 или более поздней.
НИКАКИЕ гарантии не предоставляются.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/cython3
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'git config --get remote.origin.url'
# Cwd /home/korobeinikovi/mykivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git
# Run 'git branch -vv'
# Cwd /home/korobeinikovi/mykivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
* master 5a94d074 [origin/master] Merge pull request #2244 from Chronolife-team/native_services_upstream
# Run '/usr/bin/python -m pip install -q --user \'appdirs\' \'colorama>=0.3.3\' \'jinja2\' \'six\' \'enum34; python_version<"3.4"\' \'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"\' \'pep517<0.7.0"\' \'toml\''
# Cwd None
# Apache ANT found at /home/korobeinikovi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/korobeinikovi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
# Recommended android's NDK version by p4a is: 19c
# Android NDK is missing, downloading
# Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r19c-linux-x86_64.zip
# Unpacking Android NDK
# Run 'unzip -q /home/korobeinikovi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c-linux-x86_64.zip'
# Cwd /home/korobeinikovi/.buildozer/android/platform
# Rename /home/korobeinikovi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c to /home/korobeinikovi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c
# Android NDK installation done.
# Installing/updating SDK platform tools if necessary
# Run '/home/korobeinikovi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=/home/korobeinikovi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk platform-tools'
# Cwd /home/korobeinikovi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_UPDATE

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

# Command failed: /home/korobeinikovi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=/home/korobeinikovi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk platform-tools
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/korob:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1226,unix/korob:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1226'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/ae19d927_9955_4bf9_a6b5_1924f4c2e24e'
#     LANG = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'GNOME'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     PWD = '/home/korobeinikovi/mykivy'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     USER = 'korobeinikovi'
#     LC_MEASUREMENT = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'gnome'
#     HOME = '/home/korobeinikovi'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=ed3ca3f4f0dbc95286957b9e5f9ae112'
#     JAVA_HOME = '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_UPDATE'
#     QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE = 'kvantum'
#     LC_NUMERIC = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/home/korobeinikovi/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     WINDOWPATH = '2'
#     JOURNAL_STREAM = '9:24208'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'gnome'
#     VTE_VERSION = '6003'
#     MANAGERPID = '1094'
#     LC_TIME = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     MAIL = '/var/spool/mail/korobeinikovi'
#     QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR = '1'
#     LOGNAME = 'korobeinikovi'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.133'
#     PATH = '/home/korobeinikovi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/opt/jython/bin/:/home/korobeinikovi/.local/bin:/opt/jython/bin/:/home/korobeinikovi/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     LC_PAPER = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     SHELL = '/bin/zsh'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     LC_MONETARY = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE = 'session'
#     USERNAME = 'korobeinikovi'
#     EDITOR = '/usr/bin/nano'
#     J2REDIR = '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_UPDATE/jre'
#     QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME = 'qt5ct'
#     GDM_LANG = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     INVOCATION_ID = '85336d4f97ef47f0a571924173ad2904'
#     DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=ed3ca3f4f0dbc95286957b9e5f9ae112'
#     J2SDKDIR = '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_UPDATE'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     GDMSESSION = 'gnome'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     INSIDE_NAUTILUS_PYTHON = ''
#     OLDPWD = '/home/korobeinikovi/mykivy'
#     LESS_TERMCAP_mb = '\x1b[01;32m'
#     LESS_TERMCAP_md = '\x1b[01;32m'
#     LESS_TERMCAP_me = '\x1b[0m'
#     LESS_TERMCAP_se = '\x1b[0m'
#     LESS_TERMCAP_so = '\x1b[01;47;34m'
#     LESS_TERMCAP_ue = '\x1b[0m'
#     LESS_TERMCAP_us = '\x1b[01;36m'
#     LESS = '-r'
#     _ = '/usr/bin/buildozer'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: `ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_UPDATE` вам ни о чем не говорит? Она должна быть установлена на `path/to/java/jdk`, а у вас - `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_UPDATE`

Comment: как это исправить?

Comment: Прочитайте мой первый комментарий повнимательнее... Я же сказал: `JAVA_HOME` установлена неверно. Запишите в неё путь до `java`. Не знаете как? Смотрите -  [link](https://g.zeos.in/?q=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B%20JAVA_HOME%20%D0%B2%20linux)

Comment: спасибо огромное!